# haskell: No instance for (Monoid Int) when use writer monad with haskell platform 2013 2.0.0

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ghc

```
module Main where
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

wt :: Int -> Writer Int [String]
wt x=writer(["num:"++ show x],x)


addw::Writer Int [String]
addw = do
        a <- wt 2
        b <- wt 3
        return (a*b)
```

There are 2 errors:

```
No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a do statement
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monoid Int)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: a <- wt 2
    In the expression:
      do { a <- wt 2;
           b <- wt 3;
           return (a * b) }
    In an equation for `addw':
        addw
          = do { a <- wt 2;
                 b <- wt 3;
                 return (a * b) }


No instance for (Num [String]) arising from a use of `*'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [String])
    In the first argument of `return', namely `(a * b)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return (a * b)
    In the expression:
      do { a <- wt 2;
           b <- wt 3;
           return (a * b) }
```

I use eclipse 4.4 juno with newest eclipsefp ,haskell platform 2013 2.0.0 include ghc 7.6.3,this code snippet is from learn you a haskell for great good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`Int` is not a `Monoid` by itself, becasuse there are two possible implementations: `Sum` and `Product`.</s>

Use either of them according to your needs.

---

Oopsie. Just swap around `[String]` and `Int`. The last type parameter to a Monad is always a value it produces.

Comment: it worked! wt::Int->Writer [String] Int
wt x=writer(x,["num:"++ show x])


addw::Writer  [String] Int
addw = do
        a <- wt 2
        b <- wt 3
        return (a*b)